# Editing dynamic text in swf

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash, fla

I have a task to edit text in an animation, I only got files from website with no codes. The animation is the same but is in 3 files - in .mov, .flv, and .swf. I was trying to decompile swf with various programmes, but there is only one field named text and is closed for editing (dynamic text read-only: 1). I changed that to 0 and exported into .fla, but cannot open in it in Adobe Flash.
Is there any way how to do it or am I doomed to failure?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you check the De-compiled .fla file. Are you able to create same animation after publishing it. ?

Comment: No, I can't open the new .fla file in anything.

Comment: Try to open fla file using Flash professional software. I have a doubt that the generated fla file is correct as most of the de-compiler available in the market only are not working when you have code associated in fla file